# What is the simplest way to determine which packages are related to another package that I've already installed?

Tags: apt, package-management, 17.04

By "*related*" I mean which packages are "*suggested*" and which packages are "*recommended*" by a package that I have installed.  I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 (although this should not matter) and I installed a package that had many suggested and recommended packages.

When installing, I used the "`--install-suggests`" option.  I would like to verify that those packages were, in fact, installed.  But, without having a simple command-line like "`apt-get --describe <package>`" after the installation, and not having captured all the output from the "`apt-get install`" that I did... I'm stumped as to how I may determine the particulars for a package once it has been installed.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `aptitude` for this purpose, install it if you not have it already:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

then use:

```
aptitude why pkg-name
```

e.g:

```
why libxinerama1
i   vlc Depends libxinerama1
```

Which means this package has been installed because `vlc` depends on it,
it also gives you information about "suggestions" and "recommendations".

If you want to see the other sides use something like:

```
apt-cache depends vlc --installed | grep -i rec
  Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify
  Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba
  Recommends: xdg-utils
```

which gives you a list of recommendations by `VLC`, change `rec` with `sug` for suggestions.

The other thing that I can think of is similar to `aptitude why` but not as smart of `aptitude` and that's `apt rdpends pkg`, e.g:

```
apt rdepends xdg-utils | grep -i sug
```

it will give you a list of packages that are suggesting `xdg-utils`, `aptitude` gives you the exact package that caused the installation.

You can get a better result using `--installed` option:

```
apt rdepends xdg-utils --installed xdg-utils
```

Comment: aptitude also gives a text based GUI that list packages and their full descriptions dependencies, recommends, suggest,  breaks and versions available  `sudo aptitude`. Installing with aptitude allows you to see what it will do before you commit to the action.

Comment: @Ravexina, this is my situation, exactly. Using apt-get, I as presented with the suggested packages... which were many. Forgetting that I was in a tty terminal, I accepted and the result was thousands of lines, preventing me from scrolling back to get the info.

Comment: Use `grep` to filter out the output or pip the output to `less` so you can scroll into them.

Comment: @ravery: Hi there! You have found the comments section, which is an area dedicated to critiquing and requesting clarification. To provide an answer/solution, you should use the "answer" section below (look for the big red "Post Your Answer" button). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The commands I can think of are:

1. `dpkg-query -p package_name`,
2. `apt-cache show package_name`

Information:

man dpkg:-

```
 -p, --print-avail package-name...
                  Display details about package-name, as found in
                  /var/lib/dpkg/available. Users of APT-based frontends
                  should use apt-cache show package-name instead.
```

man apt-cache:-

```
show pkg...
           show performs a function similar to dpkg --print-avail; it displays the package records for the named packages.

depends pkg...
           depends shows a listing of each dependency a package has and all the possible other packages that can fulfill that dependency.
```

3. `apt-cache depends package_name` has more to offer

Now after run the `dpends` command you can check if these packages were install with" `dpkg-query -s package_name` fro each of them

Source:

man dpkg, man dpkg-query